# Build overview of TFS azure (Preview)

Tags: monitoring, tfsbuild, azure-devops

We are in a process of evaluating tfs azure.

We've migrated three of our projects(solutions) and created a specific project for each of the solutions in tfs azure.

Now we are looking for something to enable a visual overview of the current build status for all the three projects.

I know that I can get a overview of each project, by going to it's site, but I'd like an gathered overview of all the projects.

Today we are using Jenkins, connected to our local tfs 2010, and that gives us an direct overview of all the build statuses.

Does anybody know a tool for that?

Comment: It sounds very much like the 2012 dashboards would do this for you if you hadn't opted to split into multiple team projects..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with the Windows Azure team, the respons is that they don't support this at the moment. You can get a build overview on the project level, but not on the collection level.